# Problem in download WSDL file

Tags: api

Our client use professional edition. We want to use WSDL file but i don't find in API. Any solution for this problem ? Please give your suggestions.

Thanks,
Vimal

Comment: Are you seeing the customize applications. plz refer this it may be helpful.                      https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gx2mAAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API access is not generally supported in PE Edition so there may be no WSDL to generate.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_api_access.htm

You will need to purchase the "Integration via Web Services APIs" in order to have the WSDLs appear